# Jenkins slave node browser is starting up with minimized mode in background when running as service

Tags: jenkins

when Jenkins slave node is running as service and browser is initiated background in minimized mode. how to maximize the browser?

Comment: I have found work around which i have provided below, please follow below steps in answer - In order to...

Comment: Got the same problem when running the slave node connection as a service. Solved it by starting the connection using command line /batch file.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get browser in maximized mode while running as service,

1. open the jenkins service in slave machine go to properties
2. check interact with desktop option
3. apply and restart service
4. run the jenkins job in master machine
5. goto to slave machine, wait for popup - Interact with desktop. click yes
6. browser will be initiated in visibly with minimized mode
7. maximise the browser manually
8. close the browser and stop the run
9. got to jenkins service in slave machine
10. Un-check interact with desktop option
11. apply and restart service
12. initiate run from master machine
13. browser will get initiated in maximized mode now.